# Sample n by two groups

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
d=data.frame(ID = rep(1:7,1), 
             Group1=c('A','C','B','C','C','A','B'),
             Group2=c('B','A','C','B','B','B','D'))

 ID Group1 Group2
  1      A      B
  2      C      A
  3      B      C
  4      C      B
  5      C      B
  6      A      B
  7      B      D
```

I need to randomly sample 1 case based on Group1. Group1 has three types: A, B, C. I need to sample 1 from each type.

At the same time, the sample's Group2 type is not repeated in the Group2 of the sample.

For example, if I only sample based on Group1:

```
dsample=d %>% group_by(Group1) %>%sample_n(size=1)
```

then the sample looks like this:

```
ID Group1 Group2

 1      A      B
 7      B      D
 4      C      B
```

In the sample's Group2, B is repeated in the sample. To avoid the repetition of Group2 type, when sampling according to Group1 type, sampling should select ID=2 so that the sample should look like this:

```
ID Group1 Group2

 1      A      B
 7      B      D
 2      C      A
```

Comment: can you describe more what you want?... why you dont use this: `sample(d$Group1, size=1)`

Comment: what if there wasn't  `C A` in the data, but only `C B`? Would you permit the repeat of B in Group 2?

Comment: No, then only one case of C B should be randomly selected or dropped to maintain unique types in Group2.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach: keep resampling until you get the desired outcome (or until you've failed a sufficiently large number of times that the desired outcome is likely to be impossible):

```
# data
d=data.frame(ID = rep(1:7,1), 
             Group1=c('A','C','B','C','C','A','B'),
             Group2=c('B','A','C','B','B','B','D'))

# first attempt
dsample = d %>% group_by(Group1) %>% sample_n(size=1)

# if first attempt doesn't work, try again & again (I put an upper limit at 100 runs)
i = 1
while(length(unique(dsample$Group2)) < nrow(dsample) & i < 100){
  dsample = d %>% group_by(Group1) %>% sample_n(size=1)
  i = i + 1
}

> dsample
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   Group1 [3]
     ID Group1 Group2
  <int> <fctr> <fctr>
1     1      A      B
2     3      B      C
3     2      C      A
```

If the desired unique combinations are impossible:

```
# example where "A" & "B" in Group 1 both have only "A" as Group2 values
d2=data.frame(ID = rep(1:7,1), 
             Group1=c('A','C','B','C','C','A','B'),
             Group2=c('A','A','A','C','B','A','A'))

# same code as before
d2sample = d2 %>% group_by(Group1) %>% sample_n(size=1)

i = 1
while(length(unique(d2sample$Group2)) < nrow(d2sample) & i < 100){
  d2sample = d2 %>% group_by(Group1) %>% sample_n(size=1)
  i = i + 1
}

# fail after 100 rounds of resampling
> d2sample
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   Group1 [3]
     ID Group1 Group2
  <int> <fctr> <fctr>
1     6      A      A
2     7      B      A
3     5      C      B
> i
[1] 100
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I tried it on my dataset and all Group1 did not have duplicate types but Group2 still had duplicate types. My dataset had over 900 cases and I'm pretty sure the sample should be around 300-400.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was a while loop, then I realized we could just look at how we're sampling from a different perspective. A better solution is to sample only one row at a time, then sample the next from a pool that only includes != Group1 and != Group2 of previous samples. This should be a lot faster:

```
f <- function(){
  x <- sample_n(d,1)
  x <- rbind(x,sample_n(d[which(!d$Group1 %in% x$Group1 & !d$Group2 %in% x$Group2),],1))
  x <- rbind(x,sample_n(d[which(!d$Group1 %in% x$Group1 & !d$Group2 %in% x$Group2),],1))
  print(x)
}

f()

  ID Group1 Group2
6  6      A      B
2  2      C      A
3  3      B      C
```

Random, non-duplicated output each time if you know there are at least 2 unique possible samples.

If someone has a suggestion for how to more concisely repeat functions in this way, please feel free to let me know. In general though, it seems like this way may be most efficient.

Comment: @Marble - This should be the simplest approach and work for most cases. If you want me to customize this for very small datasets that will inevitably have duplicates that need to be dropped though, let me know.

Comment: The current function only returns 3 results. What should I do if the Group1 has over 400 types?

Answer (score 0):

Try this recursive function

#### your data

```
d=data.frame(ID = rep(1:7,1), 
             Group1=c('A','C','B','C','C','A','B'),
             Group2=c('B','A','C','B','B','B','D'))

dsample=d %>% group_by(Group1) %>%sample_n(size=1)
```

#### function

```
myfun <- function(ans, allowed, restricted, counter, end) {
             allowed <- setdiff(allowed, ans)
             allowed1 <- setdiff(allowed, restricted[counter])
             if (length(allowed) == 0 | counter > end) {
                  if (length(ans) < end) {
                      ans <- c(ans, rep(NA, end-length(ans)))
                  }
                  return(ans)
             } else {
                  counter <- counter + 1
                  ans <- c(ans, sample(allowed1, 1))
                  myfun(ans, allowed, restricted, counter, end)
             }
         }
```

#### output of 10 trials

```
replicate(10,myfun(ans=NULL, unique(d$Group2), dsample$Group1, 1, nrow(dsample)))

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,] "D"  "C"  "B"  "C"  "B"  "B"  "B"  "B"  "D"  "D"  
[2,] "C"  "D"  "D"  "A"  "D"  "C"  "C"  "A"  "A"  "C"  
[3,] "A"  "B"  "A"  "D"  "A"  "A"  "D"  "D"  "B"  "B"
```

Note each replicate's output is organized column-wise